# Python: how to use struct to pack and unpack references to objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, reference, pack

I have a list of objects, for example:

```
L = [<CustomObject object at 0x101992eb8>, <CustomObject object at 0x101763908>, ...]
```

The items in the list are "references" so I guess it's like a list of unsigned integers, am I wrong?

In order to see if I can save some memory, I would like to pack this list using the struct module.

Is this possible? And if yes how to do it? (except if you know for sure I won't save memory like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` is already an array of “integers” (pointers) internally; `struct` can’t compress that in any simple or significant fashion, and doing so would interfere with Python’s garbage collection.

The `CustomObject`s (if they are unique) take more than twice as much memory—closer to a hundred times unless you use `__slots__` for the class.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I'm using __slots__, and I've just figured out that the real benefit of using struct is to reduce the number of attributes when you have a lot of small objects...